# Is there a problem with ServerFault and MyOpenID?

Tags: support, login

My Server Fault logon seems to be broken (SO, MSO and SU are all fine). When I try to logon using my 'MyOpenID' provider I get the following error on the Server Fault logon page:

> `Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:`
>
> `The signature verification failed.`

This is happening on two different machines connected to two different internet providers. I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit and Firefox 3.5.3.

I've cleared all my cookies, cache etc but the error persists.

**Update:**

How strange, this has just magically started working again. Nothing was changed at this end.

Comment: probably related to http://serverfault.com/questions/64232/dead-gateway-detection-on-windows-2008-server

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it and works for me. Ubuntu. Firefox 3.0.14

Answer (score 0):

I was also having a problem, in this case logging into meta - something along the lines of "credentials expired, try logging in again."

Just tried again, and it seems to be working now, at least for FF3.5 on XP.